# xml dom parser find tag by name in java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

I have an xml:
http://netmobileag.accu-weather.com/widget/netmobileag/weather-data.asp?slat=48.04960&slon=21.71420&metric=1

I just want to get city and temperature, i tried this:

```
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGethttp://netmobileag.accu weather.com/widget/netmobileag/weather-data.asp?slat=48.04960&slon=21.71420&metric=1");

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();

String res = "";

DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(in));
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

NodeList loc = doc.getElementsByTagName("local");

for (int i = 0; i < loc.item(0).getChildNodes().getLength(); i++) {
    res = res + "\n" + loc.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
}
```

But the res will be

```
#text
#text
 ...
```

summary 25x. How can I get the city and temperature value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right thing to do here is to use Xpath actually. Do you search in a Database with Regex or SQL? Same here, searching in XML files is done via XPath.

```
 package xpath;

 import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
 import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
 import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
 import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
 import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
 import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

 import org.w3c.dom.Document;
 import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

 public class SimpleParsing {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(false); // never forget this!
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

    Document doc = builder.parse("/Users/eugenrabii/Desktop/MyFile.xml");

    XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = xPathFactory.newXPath();

    XPathExpression xPathExpression = xpath.compile("//city/text()");

    Object result = xPathExpression.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

    System.out.println(result.toString());

    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;

    System.out.println(nodes.getLength());
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue()); 
    }
}
```

}

Comment: @Robertoq what do you mean? I am just guessing that the XML Structure changed may be? Can you provide the XML file you tested against?

Answer (score 0):

try getTextContent() instead of getNodeValue()

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGethttp://netmobileag.accu weather.com/widget/netmobileag/weather-data.asp?slat=48.04960&slon=21.71420&metric=1");

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();

String res = "";

DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(in));
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

NodeList loc = doc.getElementsByTagName("local");

for (int i = 0; i < loc.item(0).getChildNodes().getLength(); i++) {
    res = res + "\n" + loc.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getTextContent();
}
```