# Codenameone read xml tag

Tags: java, xml, codenameone

I'm using Codename One's XML parser to parse an XML file that looks like this:

```
<string name="P0001">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</string>
<string name="P0002">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</string>
<string name="P0003">cccccccccccccccccc</string>
```

I'm using the following code to parse this file:

```
XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();

Element elem = parser.parse(new InputStreamReader(myInput, "UTF-8"));

for(Element e : elem) {

   //this returns P0001/2/3
   String attr = e.getAttribute("name");

   //how do I get the aaaaaaaaa String?
}
```

So how do I get the text element in this code?

Comment: The tag is <string name = "P0001"> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</string>

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xml dom parser find tag by name in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11800931/xml-dom-parser-find-tag-by-name-in-java)

Comment: Edited the question with a better sample and nominated to reopen. It's not exactly intuitive since DOM requires a text element to be in a separate element as it doesn't "know" if you are mixing tags within the text. But this should work:            `Element child = (Element)e.getTextChildren(null, true).get(0);
           Log.p(child.getText());`

Answer (score 0):

This isn't very intuitive since DOM requires a text element to be in a separate element as it doesn't "know" if you are mixing tags within the text. E.g. something like this is totally legal XML:

```
<string>aaaaaa<sometag/>aaaaa</string>
```

So the XML parser breaks this up into separate entities so in this case it will look like:

```
Entity = String
   TextEntity = aaaaaa
   Entity = sometag
   TextEntity = aaaaaa
```

In your case this is redundant since you know there won't be tags in the middle but for compatibility DOM still uses the same semantics sp getting the text children should work like this:

```
Element child = (Element)e.getTextChildren(null, true).get(0);
Log.p(child.getText());
```

Notice I over simplified and assumed there will be no cases like `<string name="P0004">` but I'm sure you will be able to figure out how to handle that if needed...

Comment: Thank you all.
Maybe I did not explain it very well, but what I need is a function that returns the text 'aaaaaaaaaaaaa' whenever I send 'P0001' and / or 'ccccccccccccccc' when I send 'P0003' and so on. Remember that the xml file has approximately 3,500 rows. The placed example reads only the first xml record.

Thank you.

Comment: The XML in the answer goes into the for loop in the edited question it will work as expected.